# Rendering Problems: attrs.xml is not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-studio-2.2

I'm having trouble getting Android Studio to render the GUI of any of the activiy_main.xml (or any *.xml).  No matter what when I try to open the activity_main.xml file, I get a

> Rendering Problems
>
> Failed to load platform rendering library

When I go to Help --> Show log in explorer and then open it up.. I see that when I open the xml file I get this error:

> 2016-09-07 12:24:39,566 [ 373895]   INFO - .android.sdk.AndroidTargetData - File C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-24/data/res/values/attrs.xml is not found

I navigate to the path and attrs.xml definitely exists in that exact path.. it's not locked or read-only.. so I don't understand what's going on.

Please help.  I just want to get Android Studio running.  It works on my very slow laptop but I need this to work on my work laptop.  I tried reinstalling everything too and nothign.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean (on the top of Android Studio click Build -> Clean), if after the clean it still doesn't work maybe try uninstalling the Android 24 SDK through the standalone manager and then install it again (while Android Studio is not running).

Comment: just tried both and still same thing unfortunately.. thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

It could be the security settings or permissions preventing access to the file. Happens more often than you can think on enterprise managed systems where there are too many system policies applied. Change the security settings by right-clicking the `C:/Users/***/AppData/` folder. And give full permissions to everyone.

Comment: checked that.. we're a small company so these laptops are pretty much very standard right from the shop we buy it from (Dell).  thank you for your suggestion though